# Does NetBSD supports ppc64?

Tags: powerpc

Searching for ppc64 on NetBSD's website:

> site:www.netbsd.org "ppc64"

didn't returned any good hits..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ppc64

**My question:** Does NetBSD supports the ppc64 architecture? Would it work OK on an ex.: [POWER7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POWER7)?

The: http://www.netbsd.org/ports/ shows many powerpc's, but how can I be sure that it will work on a POWER7?

Comment: maybe this?: http://wiki.netbsd.org/ports/ofppc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power 7 is not the same as PowerPC.  Unless your specific machine is expliclity listed as supported in one of the powerpc ports - see http://www.netbsd.org/ports/ at bottom - you will most likely not be able to install NetBSD successfully.

For non-experts on non-x86 hardware, your best bet is most likely just using what the vendor recommends.